# How do I read contents of text file in to a dictionary with list of values associated to each key

Tags: python

I have a text file with contents in below format and would like to read them and convert data in to a dictionary

```
  A       B      C        D         E  
  815  13549516  313896   310871     310836  
 2802  21722160  505756   223391     135104
```

Expected output:

```
{A:[815, 2802], B: [13549516, 21722160], C:[313896, 507576], D: [310871,223391], E:[310836, 135104]}
```

Tried to read the file and split the contents with delimiter as ' ' or TAB but couldn't achieve the expected output

Comment: If you leave out the argument to `split()` it uses any whitespace as the delimiter, which should do what you want.

Comment: You could also try using `pandas.read_table()`.

Answer (score 1):

With `pandas` library (and its [`pd.read_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html) function) it will cost you just one single line:

import pandas as pd

```
d = pd.read_table(filepath, sep='\s+', engine='python').to_dict(orient='list')
print(d)
```

---

```
{'A': [815, 2802], 'B': [13549516, 21722160], 'C': [313896, 505756], 'D': [310871, 223391], 'E': [310836, 135104]}
```